# Analyze level sets of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, trigonometry, numerical-methods

I have the following function 
$$ f(\theta_1,\theta_2):=\left( \arccos \left( \frac{1}{3}\,\sqrt {1+8\,\cos \left( \frac{\theta _{1}}{2}-
\frac{\theta _{2}}{2}\right) \cos \left( \frac{\theta _{1}}{2} \right) \cos \left( 
\frac{\theta _{2}}{2} \right) } \right)  \right) ^{2}
$$ for $\theta_1,\theta_2 \in [-\pi,\pi]$

Is there anything we know about the level sets?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to note that 
$$1+8\,\cos \left( \frac{\theta_{{1}}}{2}-\frac{\theta_{{2}}}{2} \right) \cos
 \left( \frac{\theta_{{1}}}{2} \right) \cos \left( \frac{\theta_{{2}}}{2}
 \right) =3+2\,\cos \left( \theta_{{2}} \right) +2\,\cos \left( \theta
_{{1}}-\theta_{{2}} \right) +2\,\cos \left( \theta_{{1}} \right) 
$$
Call this $g(\theta_1, \theta_2)$.

The level sets of your function are the level sets of $g(\theta_1, \theta_2)$, because $ \arccos(\sqrt{t}/3)^2$ is one-to-one on $[0,9]$.
The gradient of $g(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ is 
$$ 2 \pmatrix{- \sin(\theta_1 - \theta_2) -  \sin(\theta_1)\cr
              \sin(\theta_1 - \theta_2) -  \sin(\theta_2)\cr} $$
Now $-\sin(\theta_1 - \theta_2) - \sin(\theta_1) = 0$ for
$$ \theta_2 = \cases{\pm \pi\cr
                     2 \theta_1 + 2\pi & for $-\pi \le \theta_1 \le -\pi/2$\cr
                     2 \theta_1  & for $-\pi/2 \le \theta_1 \le \pi/2$\cr
                     2 \theta_1 -2\pi& for $\pi/2 \le \theta_1 \le \pi$\cr}$$
Similarly $\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2) - \sin(\theta_2) = 0$ the reflection of these across the line $\theta_1 = \theta_2$.  The critical points, where the gradient is $0$, are 
$$ (\theta_1, \theta_2) = (\pm \pi, \pm \pi), (0, \pm \pi), (\pm \pi, 0), (0,0), \left(-\dfrac{2\pi}{3}, \dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right),  \left(\dfrac{2\pi}{3}, -\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)$$ 
The corresponding critical values are $0, 1, 9$: $0$ is the minimum, 
$9$ the maximum.  The critical values are where the topology of the level sets changes.  If $y$ is not a critical value, a level set $g(\theta_1, \theta_2) = y$ can only consist of smooth (possibly closed) curves. 
The level set $g(\theta_1, \theta_2) = 1$ looks like this:

[image]

consisting of the lines $\theta_1 = \pm \pi$, $\theta_2 = \pm \pi$, and $\theta_2 = \theta_1 \pm \pi$.  $g(\theta_1, \theta_2) < 1$ in the two triangles at top left and lower right, and $> 1$ in the middle region.
For $0 < y < 1$ the level set consists of two closed curves, each surrounding one of the local minima $ \left(-\dfrac{2\pi}{3}, \dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)$ and $\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{3}, -\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)$ and contained in one of the triangles.

[image]

For $1 < y < 9$ the level sets consist of a single closed curve in the middle region, surrounding the local maximum $(0,0)$.

[image]

Comment: many thanks....